# Kotlin - How to make field read-only for external classes

Tags: field, kotlin, readonly, kotlin-lateinit

I have the following Kotlin class on Android:

```
class ThisApplication: Application() {

    lateinit var network: INetwork

    override fun onCreate() {

        super.onCreate()

        network = Network()
    }
}
```

Now, any external class can get the INetwork reference by simply doing:

```
application.network
```

However, that also makes it possible for an external class to overwrite that value:

```
application.network = myNewNetworkReference
```

I want to avoid the second option. Unfortunately, I can't make the field `val` because its initialization needs to happen inside the `onCreate` callback.

I also thought about making the field private and exposing it through a function, like this:

```
private lateinit var network: INetwork
fun getNetwork() = network
```

However, whoever calls getNetwork() can still assign a new value to it, like so:

```
application.getNetwork() = myNewNetworkReference
```

How can I make the network field to be read-only by external classes? Or even better, is there a way to make it `val` even though I can't initialize it inside a constructor?

Comment: It's not true that a caller of a method can reassign the value of this method. `application.getNetwork() = myNewNetworkReference` would not compile.

Answer (score 47, accepted):

To restrict the access from the external classes, you can change the visibility of accessors. For your case, you need `private` setter and `public` getter with `lateinit` modifier:

```
lateinit var network: INetwork
    private set
```

Or a read-only lazy property:

```
val network: INetwork by lazy { Network() }  //you can access private property here, eg. applicationContext
```

There are some misunderstanding from you about this code:

```
private lateinit var network: INetwork
fun getNetwork() = network
```

Kotlin is **pass-by-value** as what [Java does](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40480/is-java-pass-by-reference-or-pass-by-value). So, `application.getNetwork() = myNewNetworkReference` is not a valid statement. We cannot assign value to the return value of a function.

Answer (score 13):

You can modify the visibility of the getters/setters independantly from the actual variable:

```
lateinit var network: INetwork
    private set
```

Answer (score 2):

Would `val network: INetwork by lazy { ... }` work for your scenario?

The lambda expression gets called with the first reference to the field `network`.  Obviously, this isn't the same as deferring initialization to the `OnCreate` method, but it is a way to make it `val` without having to initialize it in the constructor.

There are other delegation choices as well.  [The Kotlin documentation](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/delegated-properties.html#property-delegate-requirements) is worth checking out.

Comment: This will work for this particular case since the Network class does not take any parameters. Thank you. However, I've simplified the example a bit. I need a way to rely on onCreate since some instances I will be creating need a Context object already initialized. For instance, I might instantiate a SQLDatabase(this) and it needs to be inside onCreate because I am passing "this" (Context) to it.